# Issue to run single JUnit Test Suite from gradle project in Eclipse

Tags: gradle, junit, automated-tests, build.gradle

Project:    SeleniumRCTestLibraryGradle

```
System:     Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64
Gradle:     4.6, integrated in eclipse (Eclipse Marketplace: Buildship Gradle Integration 2.0, Groovy Development Tools 3.0.0)
IDE:        Eclipse 4.7.3a (Oxygen.3a)
```

Environment/System variables:

```
JAVA_HOME       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162
JAVA_PATH       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin
classpath       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\lib
path            included ";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin"
```

Project structure:

```
SeleniumRCTestLibraryGradle
|--src/main/java/com/dummy/jb/ (Own project libraries)
|--src/test/java/com/dummy/jb/ (Own Test Classes and Test Suites)
|  |--Main/Specs/*.java (Own Test Classes)
|  |--TestSuite/ (Own Test Suites)
|     |--Tenant/
|        |--ChannelX
|           |--TenantChannel_PlatformEnv_TestSuiteName.java (Single Test Suite to run)
|--JRE System Library (jre1.8.0_162)
|--Project and External Dependencies (downloaded by build.gradle configuration)
|--bin/
|--gradle/
|  |--wrapper/
|     |--gradle-wrapper.jar
|     |--gradle-wrapper.properties
|--lib/ (Other libraries)
|--src/
|--build.gradle
|--gradle.properties
|--gradlew
|--gradlew.bat
|--settings.gradle
```

**Issue:**
In Eclipse 4.7.3a (Oxygen.3a) the given test suite runs succesfully, if I start the suite in jUnit 4 mode: Right click > Run As > Run configuration > Test runner: jUnit 4 > run).
But no runs if I start as Gradle test (Right click > Run As > Gradle Test), see **console log of eclipse**:
[Click to download console log](https://www.java-forum.org/attachments/eclipsegradleconsolelog01-txt.10853/?temp_hash=96ad7a0c8d89b16b0e36650ed80e2805)

And also the **Gradle Executions log:**
[Click here to download the gradle execution log](https://www.java-forum.org/attachments/eclipsegradlefailureslog02-txt.10854/?temp_hash=96ad7a0c8d89b16b0e36650ed80e2805) 
[Click here for screenshot from Eclipse Gradle execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTZG9.png)

And also here the **Gradle project files**, including build.gradle-, gradle-wrapper.properties-, gradle.properties- and settings.gradle file:
[Click here to download the minimal project structure](https://www.java-forum.org/attachments/seleniumrctestlibrarygradle-zip.10855/?temp_hash=96ad7a0c8d89b16b0e36650ed80e2805)

I think the gradle environment find not the given test suite name or use the wrong classpath/directory.